# How can I automate recurring cash payments to an individual?

Tags: united-states, cash

(US-based question)

I currently give cash to several people on a regular basis: small cash gifts to help out unemployed relatives, tutors for my child, neighbors' children doing some yard work, and so on. The amounts range from $20 to $100/week. Is there a way to fully automate this?

Requirements:

1. Recipient can easily access funds (withdraw cash at an ATM or pay for purchases anywhere a regular debit or credit card is accepted)
2. Recipient cannot overspend (if I give them $50/week, they cannot spend more than that)
3. Funds are automatically loaded from my bank account
4. Low upfront or monthly fees and no hidden fees (inactivity fees, low balance fees, etc)

To remain practical, the solution must not add the burden of income/payroll taxes and/or reporting to tax/labor authorities (*as compared to cash - I am well aware that tax and labor laws apply to cash so let's not belabor that*).

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Why not use PayPal or Venmo or cash app or something like that?

Comment: What @quid said, and Zelle.

Comment: @quid do those let you make automatically reoccurring payments to individuals? I thought that only worked for established organisations.

Comment: There are several debit card products that are marketed as for use by minor children in this way.

Comment: You can't automate PayPal, Venmo, Zelle, etc - Some do offer recurring payments but then the individual would have to register as a business, create a subscription and then they rake them on the fees. 

Then there is a record of payments made which can potentially trigger a problem for me (e.g. if I employ my family friends' older still underage child as a tutor) or the recipient (e.g. if my unemployed friend didn't report my cash gift to the unemployment office or my poor elderly relative didn't report my cash gift to the social security office).

Comment: @spuck - Those cards are atrocious. I did try the one that comes up first if you search for "debit card for kids". First, they advertise automated weekly allowance but you have to manually transfer the money from your actual bank account, which negates the whole point. Then, my kid was never able to spend the money, not even once - there was always some security issue that required an hour on hold with customer service to authorize the payment. This is true for all these cards if you read the fine print and the reviews.

Comment: Do these recipients have checking accounts that you could set up recurring ACH payments to? The first requirement of being able to get access to the funds at an ATM or at a POS terminal means a debit card backed by an account.